# Spark: Using named arguments to submit application

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is it possible to write a Spark script that has arguments that can referred to by name rather than index in the args() array?  I have a script that has 4 required arguments and depending on the value of those, may require up to 3 additional arguments.  For example, in one case args(5) might be a date I need to enter.  I another, that date may end up in args(6) because of another argument I need.

Scalding has this implemented but I don;t see where Spark does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark does not provide such functionality.

You can use `Args` from scalding (if you don't mind the dependency for such as small class):

```
val args = Args(argsArr.toIterable)
```

You can also use any CLI library that provides the parsing features you may want.

Answer (score 7):

I actually overcame this pretty simply.  You just need to preface each argument with a name and a delimiter say "--" when you call your application

```
spark-submit --class com.my.application --master yarn-client ./spark-myjar-assembly-1.0.jar input--hdfs:/path/to/myData output--hdfs:/write/to/yourData
```

Then include this line at the beginning of your code:

```
val namedArgs = args.map(x=>x.split("--")).map(y=>(y(0),y(1))).toMap
```

This converts the default args array into a Map called namedArgs (or whatever you want to call it.  From there on, just refer to the Map and call all of your arguments by name.